# Getting vector of values from loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column which may have N/As. I am running a loop which checks if there is N/A error and pops up MsgBox with location of an error. 
What I have problem with is storing a value from corresponding column where there's an error.

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer
Dim where As Variant
Dim numbers(1 To 20) As Variant

For Each i In Range("b2:b" & lastrow)
If IsError(i) = True Then
where = Range("B" & i.Row).Address
MsgBox "Missing data was found in " & where
numbers (i) = Range("D" & i.Row).Value
End If
Next i
```

There's something wrong with this code, as a get mismatch error (run time error '13').
Please point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

Edit: I quoted just part of code, thats why there's no Sub/End Sub

Comment: if `lastrow` never gets any value, then it stays empty and `Range("b2:b" & lastrow)` will error out

Comment: its last_non_empty_row

Comment: i suggest that... I just want to make sure it is set anywhere (because it is also not declared)

Comment: also if `lastrow` is set properly but is 21+ then you will get this error... can you tell which line is highlighted when the error pops up?

Comment: As it is, it seems your code will not run because you declare `i` as an `Integer` but use it in a `For Each` which expects a variable of type `Object` (or a `Variant`).

Comment: Change your `i` variable from an `Integer` to a `Range` and your `where` variable from a `variant` to  a `string`.  You'll need to update the last row `numbers(i) = Range("D" & i.Row).Value` - `i.row` will work, but `numbers(i)` will need changing to something like `numbers(i.row-1)` - or some other ordinal number.  Took 5 minutes for that to post - and this is meant to be a fast connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Const lastrow As Integer = 10

Sub GetErrors()
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim where As Variant
    Dim numbers As Variant

    where = vbCrLf
    For Each oneCell In Range("b2:b" & lastrow).Cells
        If IsError(oneCell.Value) = True Then
            where = where & Range("B" & oneCell.Row).Address & vbCrLf
            If (Not IsArray(numbers)) Then
                ReDim numbers(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve numbers(UBound(numbers) + 1)
            End If
            numbers(UBound(numbers)) = Range("D" & oneCell.Row).Value
        End If
    Next oneCell

    MsgBox "Error was found in : " & where
End Sub
```